# htaccess won't redirect to subfolder when given uri is just the host name

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using .htaccess file to redirect all requests to index.php file located in subfolder.

Folders and files structure:

```
/var/www/html/.htaccess
/var/www/html/my-folder/index.php
```

There is nothing in the main html folder but the .htaccess file and the my-folder directory.

My .htaccess file content is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /my-folder/index.php [L]
```

All the requests actually do get redirected to the proper location, to the index.php file inside the my-folder. All requests but request that the url is just the hostname. For instance:

```
www.my-host.com/path -> Redirects correctly
www.my-host.com/path/ -> Redirects correctly
www.my-host.com/path/another-path -> Redirects correctly
www.my-host.com/file.php -> Redirects correctly
www.my-host.com -> Won't redirect
www.my-host.com/ -> Won't redirect
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `.` in your pattern means there has to be something in the URI, try making it optional or use `^` instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /my-folder/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I changed my .htaccess, and now it looks exactly like you suggested, but still the same problem.